# Issue querying date from oracle.

Tags: sql, sqldatatypes, oracle11gr2

I understand that querying a date will fail as its comparing a string to date and that can cause an issue.

Oracle 11.2 G
Unicode DB
NLS_DATE_FORMAT DD-MON-RR

```
select * from table where Q_date='16-Mar-09';
```

It can be solved by

```
select * from table where trunc(Q_date) = TO_DATE('16-MAR-09', 'DD-MON-YY');
```

What I don't get is why this works.

```
select* from table where Q_date='07-JAN-08';
```

If anyone can please elaborate or correct my mindset.
Thanks

Comment: Does the first query return an error or does it just not return any results?

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified.
The first returns no rows.
The second returns all rows to that date.
The third returns all rows to that date.
There are rows related to march 16th 2009.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle *does* allow date literals, but they depend on the installation (particularly the value of `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` as explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch4datetime.htm#NLSPG004)).  Hence, there is not a universal format for interpreting a single string as a date (unless you use the `DATE` keyword).

The default format is DD-MM-YY, which seems to be the format for your server.  So, your statement:

```
where Q_date = '07-JAN-08'
```

is interpreted using this format.

I prefer to use the `DATE` keyword with the ISO standard YYYY-MM-DD format:

```
where Q_Date = DATE '2008-01-07'
```

Comment: Thanks. 
As I've said I've check the NLS_DATE_FORMAT of the database
it is DD-MON-RR. Sorry for ambiguity I'm trying to help someone that is communicating via instant messaging client.

Comment: @KyleK . . . `'07-JAN-08'` is a valid date in the format of "DD-MON-RR".  Hence the conversion works without an error.

Answer (score 0):

If this gets no rows returned:

```
select * from table where Q_date='16-Mar-09';
```

but this does see data:

```
select * from table where trunc(Q_date) = TO_DATE('16-MAR-09', 'DD-MON-YY');
```

then you have rows which have a time other than midnight. At this point in the century DD-MON-RR and DD-MON-YY are equivalent, and both will see 09 as 2009, so the date part is right. But the first will only find rows where the time is midnight, while the second is stripping the time off via the `trunc`, meaning the dates on both sides are at midnight, and therefore equal.

And since this also finds data:

```
select* from table where Q_date='07-JAN-08';
```

... then you have rows at midnight on that date. You might *also* have rows with other times, so checking the count with the trunc version might be useful.

You can check the times you actually have with:

```
select to_char(q_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from table;
```

If you do want to make sure you catch all times within the day you can use a range:

```
select * from table where
q_date >= date '2009-03-16'
and q_date < date '2009-03-17';
```

[Quick SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7e9fdd/2).

Although it sounds like you're expecting all the times to be midnight, which might indicate a data problem.